# copy data into next available blank cell excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

the code below works fine apart from one thing, the names are copied to the second sheet in the same position as they are in in the first sheet so I end up with this.

[image: loads of blanks]

As you can see there are loads of blanks, what I need it to end up like is,

This

[image: No blanks]

There are three parts to the code as you can see

1 gather names and status

2 test the availability of the person and write their name to the second sheet if they are available

3 clear out the blanks

Is there any way I can amend the line;

Activecell.offset to place the name in the next available cell in each column as it cycles through?

I can’t use the “clear the blanks” as it screws up all the buttons positions in the second sheet

Code

```
Option Explicit
Sub Copy_all_available_names_to_sorted_sidesmen_50()
'record all the names and availability into a single array

  Dim AllData() As Variant
  Dim Name As Long, Status As Long
  Dim Storedname As String
  Dim Storedstatus As String
  Dim nameindex As Long

  Sheets("Everyones Availability").Select
  Name = Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Count - 1
  Status = Range("a3", Range("a3").End(xlToRight)).Count - 1
  ReDim AllData(0 To Name, 0 To Status)

  For Name = LBound(AllData, 1) To UBound(AllData, 1)
     For Status = LBound(AllData, 2) To UBound(AllData, 2)
        AllData(Name, Status) = Range("A3").Offset(Name, Status).Value
     Next Status
  Next Name

  Sheets("Sorted sidesmen").Select
  Range("A3").Select

  For Name = LBound(AllData, 1) To UBound(AllData, 1)
     For Status = LBound(AllData, 2) To UBound(AllData, 2)
        Storedname = AllData(Name, 0)
        Storedstatus = AllData(Name, Status)

        If Storedstatus = "Available" Then
           ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)(Name, Status).Value = Storedname
        End If
      Next Status
  Next Name

  Dim rng As Range
  On Error GoTo NoBlanksFound
  Set rng = Range("a3:z46").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

  On Error GoTo 0
  rng.Rows.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp

NoBlanksFound:
  MsgBox "All Blanks have been removed"
End Sub
```

Thank you for looking and help you may be able to give

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your source sheet? (I assume that your source sheet is called `Everyones Availability`)

Comment: You have this line: `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)(Name, Status).Value = Storedname` For us it is impossible to find out what cell is the active cell. However you should make use of a counter, usually the letter `i` is used for that. You're code offsets one row down every time. Instead of that write something like: `i = 1 ; Worksheet("Worksheetname").Cells(2+i, 1).value = Storedname` where in `.Cells(2+i,1)` the 1 indicates column A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyAllAvailableNamesToSortedSidesmen50()

    Dim wsEA As Worksheet: Set wsEA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Everyones Availability")
    Dim wsSS As Worksheet: Set wsSS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sorted sidesmen")

    Dim topEAcel As Range: Set topEAcel = wsEA.Cells(3, "A")
    Dim topSScel As Range: Set topSScel = wsSS.Cells(3, "A")

    Dim lrEA As Long:      lrEA = wsEA.Cells(wsEA.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lcEA As Long:      lcEA = wsEA.Cells(1, wsEA.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    wsSS.Range(topSScel, wsSS.Cells(lrEA, lcEA)).ClearContents  'clear Sorted sidesmen

    Dim arrEA As Variant:  arrEA = wsEA.Range(topEAcel, wsEA.Cells(lrEA, lcEA))
    Dim arrSS As Variant:  arrSS = wsSS.Range(topSScel, wsSS.Cells(lrEA, lcEA))

    Dim rEA As Long, cEA As Long, rSS As Long

    For cEA = 2 To lcEA         'by columns
        rSS = 1
        For rEA = 1 To lrEA - 2 'by rows
            If arrEA(rEA, cEA) = "Available" Then
                arrSS(rSS, cEA) = arrEA(rEA, 1)     'copy available names
                rSS = rSS + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    wsSS.Range(topSScel, wsSS.Cells(lrEA, lcEA)).Value2 = arrSS     'paste in wsSS
End Sub
```

---

Sheet1 ("Everyones Availability")

[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2 ("Sorted sidesmen")

[image: Sheet2]

---

**Key items in code:**

```
Last Row on "Everyones Availability":    lrEA
Last Col on "Everyones Availability":    lcEA

    lrEA = wsEA.Cells(wsEA.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lcEA = wsEA.Cells(1, wsEA.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Note: initial methods (xlDown, and xlToRight) were causing issues with empty cells
```

---

```
- All data on "Everyones Availability": arrEA = Variant Array (copy from)
- All data on "Sorted Sidesmen":        arrSS = Variant Array (copy to; empty before copy)

    arrEA = wsEA.Range(topEAcel, wsEA.Cells(lrEA, lcEA))
    arrSS = wsSS.Range(topSScel, wsSS.Cells(lrEA, lcEA))  'Same size as arrEA
```

---

```
If arrEA(rEA, cEA) = "Available" Then

  arrSS(rSS, cEA) = arrEA(rEA, 1)    'copy names

  rSS = rSS + 1 'separate row counter for "Sorted sidesmen", increment only if "Available"

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply sort the output in the final sheet?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Ordering()
    Dim col As Range, lastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")         'change as appropriate
        lastRow = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

       For Each col In Intersect(Range("A:D"), .UsedRange).Columns
           .Range(.Cells(3, col.Column), .Cells(lastRow, col.Column)).Sort Key1:=.Range(.Cells(3, col.Column), .Cells(lastRow, col.Column)), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo ' 'Sort to ensure in order
      Next col
    End With
End Sub
```

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you need:

Assuming your source sheet is called "Everyones Availability" and new sheet "Sorted sidesmen"

```
Sub copy_to_newsheet()

Dim i, j, lr, lc, newlr, newlc As Long

Sheets("Sorted sidesmen").Cells.ClearContents

lr = Sheets("Everyones Availability").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row '' your last row
lc = Sheets("Everyones Availability").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column '' your last column

Sheets("Everyones Availability").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, lc)).Copy
Sheets("Sorted sidesmen").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

For j = 1 To lc
For i = 3 To lr

Sheets("Sorted sidesmen").Select
Cells(1, j).Select
newlr = Selection.End(xlDown).Row '' your new last row
newlc = Selection.End(xlToRight).Column '' your new last column

If Sheets("Everyones Availability").Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then GoTo thenexti

Sheets("Everyones Availability").Cells(i, j).Copy
Sheets("Sorted sidesmen").Cells(newlr + 1, j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

thenexti:
Next
Next


End Sub
```